# How to pass a sequence of jpeg data from MATLAB to ffplay

Tags: matlab, video, video-streaming, jpeg

I want to playback sensor data from different sensors in matlab synchronously. For most data I use updating plots. However, I have difficulties to find an efficient way to playback a sequence of jpeg data as video on screen (720p or 1080p).

One way i tried is to use the matlab function to convert the jpeg data to raw matlab images (https://nl.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/readimage.html) and then display it with the *imshow* function. This way is very slow and therefore not suitable.

Another way was to write the jpeg data to a file (fwrite) and using the matlab *system* command to execute ffplay:

ffplay -loglevel panic -framerate 30 -i output.jpg

This works for showing single .jpeg's, but is becoming tricky when I want to play a sequence of jpeg data as a movie. If I write all jpeg data sequentially to a file and run ffplay afterwards, I can playback the movie correctly. But what I want to playback on the fly (i.e. stream) and not wait until all data is written to the file before playback.

Is there a suitable way to share the jpeg data from matlab directly to ffplay in order to play a sequency of jpeg data on-the-fly? Any other suggestions to tackle this problem are also welcome.

Comment: Does Matlab do `standard input/output` stuff? If yes then maybe set your input as `-i -` then use `stdin.writeBytes( your_Next_Jpeg_Bytes );`? (sends bytes to running process, eg FFPlay)